# SELECT matching multiple WHERE criterias (from linking table)

Tags: mysql, sql

I might be missing something obvious, but I need a query that returns only records that match multiple criteria on the same column.

The table is a simple linking table that links tags to photos, i.e. a tag can be applied to several photos and a photo can have several tags.

```
photoid | tagid
----------------
 343    |    2
 343    |    5
 343    |    8
 522    |    5
 522    |    1
 522    |   10
 522    |    8
 118    |    8
 118    |    5
etc...
```

As seen the photoid 343 has 3 tags.

Now, what I need is a query that gives me the photoid for all photos that have certain tags. The photos shall have *either* tagid 1 *or* tagid 2, and shall have *both* tagid 5 *and* tagid 8, but must *not* have tagid 10.
 I.e. something like 
`(tagid=1 OR tagid=2) AND (tagid=5 AND tagid=8) AND tagid!=10`. 
In the example above, only 343 would match.

I have tried with `WHERE IN` with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT`

```
SELECT PhotoTags.photoid, FROM PhotoTags
WHERE (PhotoTags.tagid) IN ((5),(8)) AND (PhotoTags.tagid) NOT IN (10)
GROUP BY PhotoTags.photoid
HAVING count(distinct PhotoTags.tagid)=2
```

This do only a part of the work, it gives me all photos matching tagid 5 and 8 but not 10. How do I add the `AND (tagid=1 OR tagid=2)` criteria to the query?

Comment: How can `tagid` be both `5` and `8`?  Also doing `tagid IN (5,8)` sort of implies `tagID != 10`.

Comment: So, you're trying to find all the `photoid`s that have *both* `tagid` 5 *and* 8?

Comment: A photo might have several tags, I'm trying to query for all photos that have certain tags. 
@Rocket: In the example I want all `photoid`s that have [_italic_]either `tagid` 1 [_italic_]or 2, AND have [_italic_]both `tagid` 5 [_italic_]and 8, AND have not `tagid` 10.

Comment: it may work for you
SELECT PhotoTags.photoid, FROM PhotoTags
WHERE (PhotoTags.tagid) IN (1,2,5,8) AND PhotoTags.tagid <>10

Comment: @KevalPithva: Isn't the `PhotoTags.tagid <>10` kinda redundant?

Comment: @AndersK: What *exact* tags are you trying to search for?

Comment: @RocketHazmat A photo might have four tags, i.e. the same `photoid` is present four times in the table with `tagid`s 2,5,8,10. In this case I don't want a match in the query since I don't wont to see any photos with `tagid`10.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the *best* solution, but it seems to work.  You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to list *all* tags for a picture, then you can use `HAVING` to filter based on what is in that value.

```
SELECT photoid, GROUP_CONCAT(tagid ORDER BY tagid ASC) AS tags
FROM PhotoTags
GROUP BY photoid DESC
HAVING tags RLIKE '(^|,)5,.*8(,|$)'
AND tags NOT RLIKE '(^|,)10(,|$)';
```

You can also try using `FIND_IN_SET` instead of a regex (`RLIKE`):

```
SELECT photoid, GROUP_CONCAT(tagid ORDER BY tagid ASC) AS tags
FROM PhotoTags
GROUP BY photoid DESC
HAVING FIND_IN_SET(5, tags) AND FIND_IN_SET(8, tags)
AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(10, tags);
```

**EDIT**: If you want to add the `OR` clause, try this:

```
SELECT photoid, GROUP_CONCAT(tagid ORDER BY tagid ASC) AS tags
FROM PhotoTags
GROUP BY photoid DESC
HAVING (FIND_IN_SET(1, tags) OR FIND_IN_SET(2, tags))
AND FIND_IN_SET(5, tags) AND FIND_IN_SET(8, tags)
AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(10, tags);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does the same thing as the original query I had, right? Can the `AND (tagid=1 OR tagid=2)` criteria be added to your example somehow?

*I have updated the description to make it clearer.*

Comment: No, it does not.  Your original query did not actually check the same photoid for multiple tags.

Comment: If you want to add the `OR` then just add that clause to the `HAVING` as well.

Comment: This gives me an error: `near "ORDER": syntax error`.

Comment: @AndersK: You could just try `GROUP_CONCAT(tagid)` then.

Answer (score 0):

if you do this

```
WHERE (PhotoTags.tagid) IN ((5),(8)) AND (PhotoTags.tagid) NOT IN (10)
```

This AND won't be taken in account because is already checking if the tagId is 5 OR 8

```
AND (PhotoTags.tagid) NOT IN (10)
```

IN can be done only comma separate value, remember that AND have priority over the OR, try this and check if it gives you the result you want, it will only select the tagid that are 5 or 8 or 1 or 2

```
SELECT PhotoTags.photoid, FROM PhotoTags
WHERE (PhotoTags.tagid) IN (5,8,1,2)
GROUP BY PhotoTags.photoid
HAVING count(distinct PhotoTags.tagid)=2
```

Comment: `(PhotoTags.tagid) NOT IN (10)` is valid SQL.  You can have a list of one value.

Comment: The suggested query, with four values in `WHERE IN` and the `count` matching 2, would match any `photoid` having two or more of the four `tagid`s. So that is not really what I'm aiming four.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to find all photos that:

- have **at least one of** the tags (1,2)
- **do not** have tag 10
- have **both** of the tags (5,8)

The first requirement can be easily handled with an `IN` clause and `SELECT DISTINCT`.

The second requirement is probably best handled using `NOT EXISTS`.

The third requirement can be handled several ways: with sub-queries, `NOT EXISTS`, `GROUP BY`/`HAVING`, etc. I'll give you an example using sub-queries, but this may not be ideal for you, especially if the number of required tags is not always 2.

Hopefully this gets you started on the right path to a solution that works well for you:

```
 select distinct t1.photoid 
 from PhotoTags t1
   inner join (
     select distinct photoid 
     from PhotoTags 
     where tagid = 5
   ) t2 on t2.photoid = t1.photoid
   inner join (
     select distinct photoid 
     from PhotoTags 
     where tagid = 8
   ) t3 on t3.photoid = t1.photoid 
 where t1.tagid in (1,2)
   and not exists (
     select NULL 
     from PhotoTags t4
     where t4.photoid = t1.photoid
     and t4.tagid = 10
)
```

Comment: That is exactly the query I want to achieve, good explanation! (I have to check whether the solutions works for me).

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work for the example.
What if I need to add one more criteria to the above, like:
"have **at least one of** of the tags (15,16)"?

Comment: You could join to an additional sub-query using `DISTINCT` and `IN`, like this: `inner join (select distinct photoid from PhotoTags where tagid in (15,16)) t5 on t5.photoid = t1.photoid `